# got error in aws lex chatbot while running it for ios application ,i am root user so all iam permission is by default applied

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have integrated AWS lex chatbor in iOS application ,but AWS throwing an error Below is the error  :

> com.amazonaws.AWSLexErrorDomain Code=0 "null" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=null, NSLocalizedFailureReason=AccessDeniedException:http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.coral.service/}

I am the root user so all I am permission is there ,dont know what i am missing ?